# Finding Fixed Points for Coupled ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have two coupled equations

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\gamma x\left(1 - \frac{\alpha x+\beta y}{N}\right)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\theta y\left(1 - \frac{\alpha x+\beta y}{N}\right)$$

where $\gamma , \alpha , \beta , \theta \space and \space N$ are constants

Next, after I nondimensionalise them by setting

$$t=\frac{\tau}{\gamma}, \quad \alpha x = X, \space \beta y = Y$$

I get

$$\frac{dX}{d\tau}=X\left(1 - \frac{X+Y}{N}\right)$$

$$\frac{dY}{d\tau}=\kappa Y\left(1 - \frac{X+Y}{N}\right)$$

Now I attempt to find the fixed point by setting both ODEs = $0$

I get $X = 0 \text{ or } X = N - Y $ from the first ODE. And when I attempt to substitute $ X  = N - Y $ into the second ODE so that I solve them simuteneously, I get $\kappa Y(1-1) = 0 $.

So I have difficulty finding the fixed point at $ X  = N - Y $

Is there another method someone could recommend? Or is there a problem in my nondimensionalization methods?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are both non zero, then there is a continuum of equilibria. Along the line $Y=N-X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
X\left(1-\frac{X+Y}{N}\right)=0\\[2mm]
\kappa Y\left(1-\frac{X+Y}{N}\right)=0\\[2mm]
\end{align}

By cases:

1. $(X,Y) = (0,0)$ satisfies the system.
2. $(X=0,Y\neq0)\implies Y=N$
3. $(X\neq 0,Y=0)\implies X=N$
4. $(X\neq0,Y\neq0)\implies Y=N-X$

Nothing else can happen here.